# Android Studio Issue: Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

Tags: android

I am googling for this issue from 2-3 hour but not able solve, I have re-install Android Studio...I have tried every solution from google....but not solved.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex'
```

**Caused by:**

`org.picocontainer.defaults.PicoInvocationTargetInitializationException: InvocationTargetException: java.io.FileNotFoundException C:\Users\Unity Developer\.AndroidStudio1.5\system\index\stubs\.versions\dom.elementClass.ver` (The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete C:\Users\Unity Developer.AndroidStudio1.5 folder. Close Android Studio and delete this file.

Or

Try a complete uninstallation and re-install. Make sure you use the latest version of Java and follow [installation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) correctly.

1. Run the uninstaller for Anroid Studio
2. Go to C:\Users[YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME]
   delete .android, .AndroidStudio and any versions of this directory with versions on the end, .gradle and .m2.
3. Then, go to
   C:\Users[YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME]\Roaming and delete the JetBrains directory.
4. Finally, go to C:\Program Files and delete the Android directory.
5. To remove the SDK go to C:\Users[YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME]\AppData\Local
   and delete the Android directory.